# PHPUnit: Is it possible to add data sets containing the same tables into a composite data set?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

According to the PHPUnit documentation (http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/database.html#understanding-datasets-and-datatables), we can add datasets containing the same table into a composite data set, and "When several datasets contain the same table the rows are appended in the specified order".  However, within the PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_CompositeDataSet::addDataSet() method, it has the following code:

```
    foreach ($dataSet->getTableNames() as $tableName)
    {
        if (in_array($tableName, $this->getTableNames()))
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("DataSet contains a table that already exists: {$tableName}");
        }
    }

    $this->dataSets[] = $dataSet;
```

Am I missing something or is the documentation incorrect??

Answer (score 2):

In order to add multiple datasets involving the same table, you'll need to extend the CompositeDataSet class and override the addDataSet method to the following:

```
   public function addDataSet(PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_IDataSet $dataSet)
    {
        foreach ($dataSet->getTableNames() as $tableName)
        {
            if (in_array($tableName, $this->getTableNames()))
            {
                $this->getTable($tableName)->addTableRows($dataSet->getTable($tableName));
                return;
            }
        }

        $this->dataSets[] = $dataSet;
    }
```